# need assistance resizing a bitmap file

Tags: c

I am trying to resize a bitmap file. The file is just a regular file taken from the command prompt, takes a integer that determines how much the file will be resized by, and, once taken in, is processed and outputs the resized image of that file. I feel like I'm close, but close doesn't always count. Here is the code I have:

```
for (int i = 0, BHeight=abs(bi.biHeight);i<BHeight; i++)
{
    buffer = malloc(sizeof(RGBTRIPLE) * bi.biWidth); 

    // iterate over pixels in scanline
    for (int j = 0; j < bi.biWidth; j++)
    {
        fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inptr);
        // temporary storage
        for (int k=0; i<factor;k++)
        {
            buffer[k]=triple;
        }

    }    //iterate over each pixel factor times  

    // write RGB triple to outfile 
    for(int i=0;i<factor;i++)
    {
        fwrite(&buffer[i], sizeof(RGBTRIPLE),1,outptr); 
    } 
}
```

Maybe someone can steer me in the right direction. Also, I purposefully did not post all the code. But if all is needed to diagnose the problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Your I/O is scary, you probably should load all of the image into memory *before* starting the processing.

Most scaling algorithms will require 2D access for neighboring pixels; scaling one scanline at a time makes it impossible to filter properly and will give poor results.

Also, of course you must modify the bitmap file's header and emit a properly adjusted header after the scaling.

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
for (int k = 0; i < factor; k++)
{
    buffer[**k**] = triple;
}
```

First of all change the variable `k` in `buffer[k]`, you have to initialized a new variable `buffer[*]`, which value is equal to the number of times the loop was run,
 otherwise if the loop continues, the value of buffer will overwrite.

---

And in code below

```cpp
// write RGB triple to outfile 
for(int i = 0; i < factor; i++)
{
    fwrite(&buffer[i], sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outptr); 
}
```

You not need to use index of the buffer in `buffer[i]`, because as the `fwrite` function write into outfile, the cursor automatically shifted to next blank position, like that if you type something by your keyboard, the cursor automatically shifted to right.
And, now you are suppose to write a scan-line or row, factor time to outfile, so need to use `bi.biWidth` instesd of `1`.
Because you need to write a whole row or `scanline` instead of one pixel.

---

So your corrected code will liked that:

```cpp
// iterate over pixels in scanline
for (int j = 0; j < bi.biWidth; j++)
{
    int cur = 0;
    fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inptr);
    // temporary storage
    for (int k = 0; i < factor; k++)
    {
        buffer[cur] = triple;
        cur++;
    }

}    //iterate over each pixel factor times  

// write RGB triple to outfile 
for (int i = 0; i < factor; i++)
{
    fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), bi.biWidth, outptr); 
}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: What if one would like to scale the BMP file by a float and not an integer? It seems quite clear that simply changing the factor to be a float with atof(argv[1]) will not do the trick...